# Spring @Transactional not working when lazily loading

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, lazy-loading

I'm working on a small maven (multi-module) project that handles a book store.

I'm currently having problems when lazily loading a collection of entities

A user has a collection of orders, which is lazily loaded.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: edu.flst.bookstore.domaine.bo.User.orders, could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:137)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:242)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.prepareDestinationList(MappingProcessor.java:881)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.addOrUpdateToList(MappingProcessor.java:806)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.addOrUpdateToList(MappingProcessor.java:894)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapListToList(MappingProcessor.java:730)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapCollection(MappingProcessor.java:580)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapOrRecurseObject(MappingProcessor.java:453)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapFromFieldMap(MappingProcessor.java:361)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapField(MappingProcessor.java:307)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:267)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapToDestObject(MappingProcessor.java:216)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.createByCreationDirectiveAndMap(MappingProcessor.java:196)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapGeneral(MappingProcessor.java:170)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:104)
org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:99)
org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:120)
edu.flst.bookstore.transverse.utils.mapper.MapperUtils.map(MapperUtils.java:30)
edu.flst.bookstore.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.rechercher(UserServiceImpl.java:26)
edu.flst.bookstore.presentation.controller.HomeController.index(HomeController.java:20)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

I'm currently using Tomcat, so I can't add JTA transactions.

I used Spring's JPA Transaction manager to handle transactions.

```
<!-- ============================= -->
<!-- TRANSACTION MANAGER           -->
<!-- ============================= -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

The bean is in my persistence layer spring context file.

I've added the @Transactional annotation to my abstract service (all my services extend this class)

```
@Service
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractServiceImpl {

    @Autowired protected UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired protected OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired protected BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired protected Mapper mapperService;

}
```

It actually doesn't work. I tried setting the annotation in my repository interface (I'm using Spring data JPA) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Show us how, in your HomeController, you get an instance of UserServiceImpl. Also make sure you have <tx:annotation-driven/> in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem occurs if you retrieve an entity that contains a lazy reference and you dereference this for the first time when you already left the transaction context. Dereferencing is not possible there as the reference wasn't retrieved from the database. AFAIK there are three solutions to this problem:

- use eager fetching to get everything from the database
- fetch necessary lazy references in your database access layer to make them available
- use long lasting transactions that are kept open even after the actual database access layer